# How to Fill ? For Prepared Statement in below case

Tags: java, oracle, csv, prepared-statement

**Java Insert Statement:**

```
insert into temp2(NO,NAME,DATE) values(?,?,?)
```

I have received a csv in any one of format below even it may change in formats.

How can I insert this statement using PreparedStatement in java?

It may be like this...

```
NO,NAME,DATE
1,BALA,24-02-1987
2,BALA,24-02-1987

     (OR)

NO,DATE,NAME
1,24-02-1987,BALA
2,24-02-1987,BALA

     (OR)

DATE,NAME,NO
24-02-1987,BALA,1
24-02-1983,BALA,2
```

How to handle this?

Comment: That'a a bad if not worst idea to have a flat file come in with different formats everytime. Too error prone.

Comment: And Oracle itself should have some sort of `load` utility.  It may be able to read the header records and figure out which column goes where.  Otherwise, you're going to want to dump to a temp table, so that you can than perform a bulk `INSERT` to the real table, with data conversion if necessary.